# AndroidTV Leanback library default navigation scaling makes vector drawable edges scratched, jagged, ugly

Tags: android, scaling, android-vectordrawable, image-scaling, leanback

Inserting VectorDrawable graphic inside viewholders in main grid of leanback makes them look ugly when focused. There is some scaling issue that i cannot resolve.

Here is simple example in normal application:

ic_vawe.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="986.5dp"
    android:height="87.27dp"
    android:viewportWidth="986.5"
    android:viewportHeight="87.27">
  <path
      android:fillColor="#FF000000"
      android:pathData="M464.46,86.61c-24.27,0.49 -63.93,0.66 -62,0.66h584V26.68C716.37,26.72 694.13,78.17 464.46,86.61Z"
      android:strokeAlpha="0.5"
      android:fillAlpha="0.5"/>
</vector>
```

Activity.kotlin

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var iv = this.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView_1);
        var d3 = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_wave);
        iv.setImageDrawable(d3);

        iv.setOnClickListener {
            iv.scaleY = iv.scaleY + 0.6F;
        }
    }
}
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView_1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When im scaling this vector up, then i got those shattered edges (look at video):
[image: android_simple_example]

That behaviour is extremely visible when navigating in AndroidTV Leanback library where there is a **lot of navigation related scaling**. Image is sharp only in one state... Look at those ugly edges:

[image: ATV_REAL_LIFE_EXAMPLe]

Please, help me smooth this edges od VectorDrawables in android TV project. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Please try use PNGs images instead of xml drawables.